# Class AB RF Amplifier with only one active device

Tags: pcb, amplifier, rf

I'm designing an amplifier for the 420-440MHz band. I'm looking at using the following part from Ampleon: [BLP15H9S100](https://www.ampleon.com/products/general-purpose-wideband/50-v/BLP15H9S100.html). I'm new to doing RF amplifier work and I've been going through the design process in ADS to try and get the design made. I was going to work with the device in the class A region where  Vgs = 3.25 volts and Vds = 50 volts. When I look at the datasheet for the part though, they provide a sample PCB on page 5 that describes a "production class-AB amplifier". Operating in AB mode would be good due to the increased efficiency. However, the design only uses one of the BLP15H9S100s in the RF path.

My question is, how are they able to design a class AB amplifier with only one active device? Is this not going to severely clip the signal and result in distortion across the device? I've seen in some tutorials that for a Class B amplifier you can use an ideal LC resonator to make up for this clipping but on the PCB there doesn't seem to be anything like this. The amplifier I'm working on is going to be used to communicate with CubeSats primarily with FSK modulation. I wasn't sure if this had an impact on the design architecture I would need to use.

Comment: Class AB and B (and others) do indeed generate signal distortion, which is typically manifested as the appearance of harmonics of your fundamental. These can then be filtered out either through a matching network or purpose built filter (or both). An additional type of nonlinearity called third order intermodulation, resulting from mixing between harmonics, is more difficult to combat however.

Comment: I see an L1 on the drain in the layout....

Comment: What is your power budget?  That'll play a lot into the architecture you can/should use.

Comment: For the third-order intermodulation, this is going to occur regardless of whether the device is operating in A AB or B mode correct? As I understood it, the third-order intermodulation non-linearity is more of a general characteristic of the device and is not impacted by the operating condition as much as the other harmonics generated by clipping would be.

Comment: @Aaron that inductor is for the power bias. My power budget can be whatever, I would prefer for this to not be a super power-hungry device but I can deal with the 50% efficiency of class A. I was just curious what the trade offs of AB with only one device were.

Comment: I guess I meant more of, what is the RF power budget?  How much power you need to TX will affect the architecture chosen, also, the bandwidth of the signal.  Wide bandwidth needs more linear amp.

Comment: One way to think about the distortion caused by using only a single device is that you are multiplying each period of your input signal by a rectangular window that only spans half the signal period. The Fourier transform of this product is a convolution of your signal with a delta train weighted by the sinc function -- which is where the harmonics come from. Provided the FSK modulation rate and deviation is sufficiently small (ie the bandwidth of the signal is smaller than the signal frequency, virtually always a good approximation), filtering the harmonics should yield the desired signal.